# Org-Ref LaTeX citation (v3) export not working correctly

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-ref

I am writing my dissertation in org-mode with org-ref to handle citations. I can not get a multi-source multi-note citation to export correctly.

Here is the org-mode code:

```
[[cite:On Van Tillian apologetics see &frame15_apolog; and
&frame95_cornel_van_til; One example in systematic theology is
&frame13:-system-theol; Finally on christian worship see
&frame97_contem_worsh_music; and &frame96_worsh_spirit_truth]]
```

Which exports to:

```
\cite[On Van Tillian apologetics see][]{frame15_apolog,frame95_cornel_van_til,frame13:-system-theol,frame97_contem_worsh_music,frame96_worsh_spirit_truth}}
```

Notice that only the first note is exported and then it is just the sources.

I do have the fallback of using multiple `[[cite:source][text::text]]` blocks, but I'd rather use the new syntax if it works.

Comment: I suspect that you'll have better luck with this on the Org mode ML, although @JohnKitchin will probably see this at some point (depending on his teaching/research load). But others interested in citation might not frequent  Emacs SE.

Answer (score 1):

I also cross-posted this question to the org-mode mailing list per @NickD's suggestion and I then added it to the issues for the org-ref github by @JohnKitchin's request.

The solution is: I need to use `cites:` in place of `cite:` and make sure I am using biblatex as my backend for bibliography seeing as it handles the `cites:` format and bibtex does not.

[See brief discussion here](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues/1010)